# Barcode scanner does not work in Portrait mode Xamarin form

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am working on PDF417 barcode scanner using ZXing via this [code](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) in iOS device .  Barcode scanning work fine in Landscape mode but does not work in Portrait mode.

I have also tried to alter some on Orientation change but no success. Does anyone ran the similar type issue? Any idea or suggestion would be great.

for Orientation, below is the code

```
public void ResizePreview (UIInterfaceOrientation orientation)
    {
    if (previewLayer == null)
        return;

    previewLayer.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, this.Frame.Width, this.Frame.Height);

    if (previewLayer.RespondsToSelector (new Selector ("connection")) && previewLayer.Connection != null)
    {
        switch (orientation)
        {
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                previewLayer.Connection.VideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                previewLayer.Connection.VideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight;
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
                previewLayer.Connection.VideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait;
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                previewLayer.Connection.VideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

for capturing Barcode below is the code

```
buttonScanDefaultOverlay.Clicked += async delegate {
            var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions {
                    TryHarder = true,
                    //CameraResolutionSelector = HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate,
                    PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.PDF_417 }
                };
                //options = ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions.(HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate);

                scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage (options);
                scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
                    scanPage.IsScanning = false;

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                        Navigation.PopAsync ();
                        DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
                    });
                };

                await Navigation.PushAsync (scanPage);
            };
```

Comment: show some code that you have tried

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati updated question with code. Have you ever faced such type of issue\